# Create a list of elements and sum it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I am starting in Python and need to compute the P&L of a portfolio composed of actions and their initial price. I have a list with the actual prices of the market also.

Actually I want to sum all the elements I have in my pnl function but that doesn't work whereas it is a list, any ideas of what can I do ??

Here is my code :

```
aapl = [ 10, 154.12 ]
goog = [  2, 812.56 ]
tsla = [ 12, 342.12 ]
fb   = [ 18, 209.0  ]

portfolio = [aapl, goog, tsla, fb]

market = [ 198.84, 1217.93, 267.66, 179.06 ]

sum(market)


for i in range(0,4):
    pnl = portfolio[i][0] * (market[i] - portfolio[i][1])
print(pnl)

type(pnl)
```

Thank you !

Comment: add tabulation to your code

Comment: You're assigning to `pnl` 4 times instead of adding to it. First, create `pnl = 0` and then in each loop iteration call `pnl += portfolio[i][0] * ...`

Comment: Thanks that's great !

Answer (score 1):

you just have to define `pnl` list before your `for` loop than just to append each item calculated in the `for` loop,  at the end you can sum your list elements:

```
aapl = [ 10, 154.12 ]
goog = [  2, 812.56 ]
tsla = [ 12, 342.12 ]
fb   = [ 18, 209.0  ]

portfolio = [ aapl, goog, tsla, fb ]

market = [ 198.84, 1217.93, 267.66, 179.06 ]

sum(market)

pnl = []
for i in range(0,4):
    pnl.append(portfolio[i][0]*(market[i]-portfolio[i][1]))

print(sum(pnl))
```

**output:**

-`174.49999999999943`

if you do not care to keep each `pnl` value in a list:

```
pnl = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    pnl += portfolio[i][0]*(market[i]-portfolio[i][1])

print(pnl)
```

**output:**

-`174.49999999999943`

if you want one line you can use:

```
sum(p0 * (m - p1) for [p0, p1], m in zip(portfolio, market))
```

**output:**

-`174.49999999999943`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a running total, like this:

```
profit = 0
for (shares, init_price), market_price in zip(portfolio, market):
    profit += shares * (market_price - init_price)
print(profit)
```

or you could use `sum` on a list comprehension:

```
profit = sum(shares * (market_price - init_price)
    for (shares, init_price), market_price
    in zip(portfolio, market))
```